# Align an image and text in same line

Tags: html, css

I want to align an image and `h1` in the same line. I have attached my source code and it doesn't work. can someone tell what's wrong with it.

```
<head>
    .header img{
        float: left;
        width: 2px;
        height: 3px;
        background: #555;
    }
    .header h1{
        position: relative;
        top: 18px;
        left: 10px;
    }

    <title> home page </title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="header">
        <img src="greenlock.jpg" alt="logo" />
        <h1> UNIVERCITY OF GREENLOCK <h1>        
    </div>
```

Comment: You could just remove the positioning (and float) and display them both as inline-block elements

Answer (score 0):

use `display : inline-block`

```css
.header img{
                display:inline-block;
                width:10px;
                height:3px;
                background:#555

    }
    .header h1{
                display:inline-block;
                 position: relative;
    }
```

```html
<div class="header">
<img src="greenlock.jpg" alt="logo" />
<h1> UNIVERCITY OF GREENLOCK <h1>        
</div>
```

you can also use `float:left` to image and `float:right` to the header

```css
.header img{
                float:left;
                width:10px;
                height:3px;
                background:#555

    }
    .header h1{
                flaot:right;
                 position: relative;
    }
```

```html
<div class="header">
<img src="greenlock.jpg" alt="logo" />
<h1> UNIVERCITY OF GREENLOCK <h1>        
</div>
```

Comment: no problem :) glad to help maybe you can accept the answer now? :P

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
 .header img{
  width:2px;
  height:3px;
  background:#555;
  vertical-align: middle;

}
.header h1{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: I could not get what you are trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

In a situation like this, where the image is essentially *part of the heading*, I would have the image which sits beside the `<h1>`, not as an `<img>` at all but as a `background` style rule applied to the `<h1>`:

```css
h1 {
margin: 18px 0 0 10px;
padding-left: 30px;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 24px;
text-transform: uppercase;
background: url('http://placehold.it/24x24') no-repeat left top rgb(255,255,255);
}
```

```html
<header>
<h1>University of Greenlock</h1>        
</header>
```

Comment: You are welcome, @asiri. If you would like to, please accept the answer above. Alternatively, if you have any further questions, please ask and I will do what I can to help.